# open webview when click items of list [android]

Tags: android

in the following when click the first item of list(open1)opened 1.html but  when second item of list(open10)again opened 1.html

I want when click second item of list(open10)opened 10.html(And so the next item...)

what can i do?

Main.class:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
private static final String[] items = { "open1","open10"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label,items));
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {
           String title="file:///android_asset/1.html",des="file:///android_asset/10.html";
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,WebViewActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);
             intent.putExtra("DES", des);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
       });
}}
```

WebViewActivity.class:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title  = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE");
    String  des = intent.getStringExtra("DES");
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.loadUrl(des);
}}
```

Comment: You are sending the same path for both listitem1 and listitem2;

Comment: What should I write code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array like this.

```
String[] mFilepath = new String[] { "file:///android_asset/1.html",
            "file:///android_asset/10.html" };
```

And then send the appropriate path to the receiver class.

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

private static final String[] items = { "open1","open10"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label,items));


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,WebViewActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);
             intent.putExtra("DES", mFilepath[position]);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
       });
}}
```

And load this URL in WebViewActivity class. Please feel free to ask if there is any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code to Opening a new WebView from List Item: `Position` is used to start `WebView` with every Item from the `ListView`

```
list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            WebView webView = new WebView(v.getContext());
                            String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_urls);
                            webView.loadUrl(urls[position]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

And Create a `string-array.xml` file inside `values` and put all web addresses as `<item>` of `<resources>` as bellow:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="bookmark_urls">
        <item>http://www.google.com</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.facebook.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This works amazingly.